# Correct use of ActiveModel with spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

A new project with the RSpec 3.2 and Rails 4.2.

As a good citizen I'm trying to do the "right" thing with the new RSpec (disable monkey patching, do not infer the type of examples etc).

The problem I have is that I want to test this little class:

```
# app/models/session.rb

class Session # NOTE: This is a simple transient class, almost plain Ruby class
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :email, :password
end
```

with something like:

```
# spec/models/session_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Session, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of :email }
  it { should validate_presence_of :password }
end
```

Obviously, when I run the spec I'm getting the `uninitialized constant Session (NameError)` which makes sense as the 'spec_helper' does not do anything to load that particular class.

I could have user the `rails_helper` instead but that is simply too much for that little class since it has nothing to do with rails at all.

Willing to do "the right" I'm puzzled with the following questions

1. Does the `Session` spec even need to be marked with `type: :model`?
2. Should I modify the `spec_helper` to change the `$LOAD_PATH`?
3. If not, is there a way to autoload `session.rb` file but without loading up the whole Rails?
4. Should the transient `Session` class be under `app/models`? I treat it as a model, it's just not persistent.

The easiest thing to do is of course to just use `rails_helper`, but for what I need to do that is unnecessary and I'd love to keep the spec file fast.

Answer (score 0):

The point of distinguishing between `rails_helper` and `spec_helper` is that you want just a minimal setup with `spec_helper`, so I would recommend against modifying `$LOAD_PATH` there. The only advantage you get is that specs run quicker if you run *only* specs that use *only* `spec_helper`, for example when you run just the single spec file with `rspec spec/models/session_spec.rb`. If you run the entire suite and require `rails_helper` in *any* spec, it will generally not run any faster.

Basically, you have two options:

1. If you don't bother about the single spec file running a bit slower than it could, and you don't want to require the `Session` model manually, I would say it's perfectly fine to use `rails_helper` for the sake of simplicity.
2. If you actually *do* care about the single spec file running a bit faster, you can `require_relative '../app/models/session'` manually at the top of the spec file. Autoloading is Rails magic, and you don't want Rails for speed reasons; therefore, you need to do it manually.

You don't need to mark the spec as `type: :model` unless you have specific spec helpers that are only included for `type: :model` and you intend to use them. However, it makes sense to mark them that way when you treat it like a regular model and use `rails_helper`.

Comment: Manual require is my best bet but unfortunately it will break autoloading when the whole test suite will be executed. Basically the file will be loaded twice (if I remember correctly) and I had numerous issues with it in the past.

Comment: Have you tried it? Autoloading should be smart enough to detect already loaded classes. Still, I think the relatively tiny speedup is not worth the effort, if I may say so.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like using `rails_helper` is the way to go. Autoloading is pretty dumb and has lots of issues that are likely to appear in med-large rails project. For example: http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Comment: Great blog post, thanks for the link. I still think this should not be an issue. There are two possibilities: Autoloading kicked in during another spec that refers to `Session`, so the file is already required and `require_relative` in your spec won't do anything. Or, your spec is the first that loads `Session`, then `const_missing` is not called at all and autoloading will be bypassed completely.